# FMX StringGrid Column Header Background

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, columnheader, stringgrid

**SOLVED:** I'm trying to change the background color of the column header on an FMX StringGrid using the onDrawColumnHeader. I can change the column header color but I lose the Header Text and Header Grid Lines.

What is the proper way to change the background color of the Column Headings so I can still see the text and grid lines?

Here is the code I'm using:

```
procedure TfrmCustomers.GridDrawColumnHeader(Sender: TObject; const Canvas: TCanvas;
  const Column: TColumn; const Bounds: TRectF);
begin
  //Exit;
  Canvas.Fill.Kind := TBrushKind.Solid;
  Canvas.Fill.Color := TAlphaColors.LightBlue;
  Canvas.FillRect(Bounds,1);
end;

object lytGrid: TLayout
  Align = Client
  Padding.Left = 2.000000000000000000
  Padding.Top = 2.000000000000000000
  Padding.Right = 2.000000000000000000
  Padding.Bottom = 2.000000000000000000
  Size.Width = 640.000000000000000000
  Size.Height = 398.000000000000000000
  Size.PlatformDefault = False
  TabOrder = 2
  object Grid: TStringGrid
    Align = Client
    CanFocus = True
    ClipChildren = True
    Size.Width = 636.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 394.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    StyleLookup = 'GridStyle1'
    TabOrder = 2
    RowCount = 55
    OnDrawColumnHeader = GridDrawColumnHeader
    Viewport.Width = 616.000000000000000000
    Viewport.Height = 353.000000000000000000
  end
end
```

Here is a screen shot of the light Blue column headings:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to incorporate the Canvas.Filltext into the process.

Here's the code I finally came up with. It has a nice little side effect of centered column headings. The tricky bit was figuring out how to get the Column Header text. I found a nice piece of code in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43479110/195983) that made it kind of easy to figure out.

```
procedure TfrmCustomers.GridDrawColumnHeader(Sender: TObject; const Canvas: TCanvas;
const Column: TColumn; const Bounds: TRectF);
var
   R : TRectF;
begin
    R := Bounds;
    Canvas.Fill.Kind := TBrushKind.Solid;
    Canvas.Fill.Color := TAlphaColorRec.Dimgray;
    Canvas.FillRect(R,1);
    R.Inflate(0,0,-0.25,-0.25);
    Canvas.Fill.Color := TAlphaColorRec.Whitesmoke;
    Canvas.FillRect(R,1);
    Canvas.Fill.Color := TAlphaColors.Black;
    Canvas.Font.Style := [TFontStyle.fsBold];
    Canvas.FillText(Bounds,Grid.ColumnByIndex(Column.Index).Header,False,1,[],TTextAlign.Center,TTextAlign.Center);
   end;
```

The first FillRect paints the entire cell Dimgray. The second FillRect paints the cell WhiteSmoke with a small little twist. Before calling the FillRect, the RectF is reduced sligtly on the right side and on the bottom edge. This lets a tiny sliver of the Dimgray from the first RectF through which acts as a border.

[image]